# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE import only the firsy row

Tags: mysql, database, csv, input, import

I have this table in mysql:

```
(IDprog, data1, data2, @Altro1, @Altro2)
```

where IDprog is the primary key, auto increment

I'm trying to upload a table from a csv in this way:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(data1, data2, @Altro1, @Altro2)
```

But.... it only uploads the first row, even if the csv contain 5k rows...
There are other similar questions in StackOverflow, and I tried all the possible solution.. without solving the problem!

I read that sometimes the problem is the "Lines Terminated By", but in this situation '\r\n' is right!
Could you please help me?
Thank you,
Manuel

Comment: Try changing it to `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` and see if it works.

Comment: please add first 5 rows of csv file as text to the question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I solved it simply deleting the line `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`. I don't know exactly why, but now it is working.